# Castle Windsor IInterceptor Configuration (Nancy bug)

Tags: castle-windsor, nancy, castle-dynamicproxy

So I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Windsor/issues/5) with the Windsor bootstrapper for Nancy. I managed to whip together a small test project where I can reproduce what is going wrong. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/Lodewijk-S/WindsorInterceptorTest/blob/cd4af4d39f1cfb3025501d7ebc7259ad1efb5d1b/WindsorInterceptorTest/Program.cs).

What seems to go wrong is this: DynamicProxy only seems to catch the invocation of the `void Handle(Action<string> oncomplete)` method and not the `string Handle(string input)` method that is called <strike>on another thread</strike>. <strike>As if the `Engine` is no longer proxied after it had been sent to another thread.</strike> Scratch that: It's just the call to another method on the same class that is not proxied.

This means the output of the program is only

```
Handled Handle with return type System.Void
test
```

and not

```
Handled Handle with return type System.Void
Handled Handle with return type System.String
test
```

Is this the expected behaviour of Dynamic Proxy? That proxies on another thread are not longer, well, proxied? Or is there something wrong with the code?

EDIT: Just RTFM'd Dynamic Proxy, and it seems like it [Works As Intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633914/castle-dynamic-proxy-not-intercepting-method-calls-when-invoked-from-within-the/). Now how do I configure my IEngine Instance to use the correct kind of Proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing :

```
Component.For<MyEngine>().Forward<IEngine>().Interceptors<ScopeInterceptor>());
```

into

```
Component.For<MyEngine>().Forward<IEngine>().Forward<MyEngine>().Interceptors<ScopeInterceptor>());
```

I don't have the time to actually try it but this should force windsor into creating a class proxy, which should solve your issue

Kind regards,
Marwijn.

-- edit --

for the current link try replacing :

```
Component.For<IEngine>().ImplementedBy<Engine>()
```

with:

```
Component.For<IEngine, Engine>().ImplementedBy<Engine>()
```

Comment: Sorry, the link to my project was not on the correct revision. The revision you looked at actually contained working code, but I don't really want to subclass `Engine` like I did in the revision you looked at.

Comment: Jep, just edited it. The thing is, if I'm going to subclass Engine, then I don't need DynamicProxy anymore. So I want to avoid that if possible

Comment: This is what forces Windsor to use the Class Proxy. So, accepted the answer. Sadly a class proxy doesn't solve my underlying problem...